# Years missing in Views' exposed field

Tags: views, 8

I have media content I want to add an option for viewers can view by year from select option. I have added Published on and then checked on exposed with year checkbox as you seen in snapshot but it showing as field instead years like: 2018, 2019 in dropdown/select option.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The 1st problem is select/option should show as years like 2018, 2019 so on.... and 2nd problem is when I  clicked on apply filter it showing query as `?sort_by=publish_on&sort_order=DESC` so manually I changed it to `?sort_by=2019&sort_order=DESC` but still not showed posts which published on 2019.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. I guess you want to FILTER by year (not sort!). Then you can SORT ascending or descending. (The year checkbox within the sort criteria is only the granularity, meaning a date like 2019-12-31 would be treating exactly the same as a date like 2019-01-01)

Comment: @Hudri exactly I want to that but I am just trying to filter by year not whole date eg: 2019-01-01

Comment: You can create an exposed filter criteria with "Grouped Filters". This allows to manually define filter options like *(Label) 2019* => *(Criteria: Is Between) 2019-01-01 & 2019-12-31*. But you have to create each year manually.

Comment: it's not dynamic like every upcoming year I need to add new group eg: 2020, 2021 ...

Comment: later I have tried with group options and added value between 2018-01-01 00:00:00 to 2018-12-31 23:58:00 with option title of 2018 then go to frontend and select 2018 option and apply so then none of posts are shown..

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of your grouping options? What operator did you use?

Comment: @pkros sorry I chose wrong field published on,It's strange in Drupal they are using authored on field which works fine and posts are shown.